# How to add a shuffle function into this code and also keep the answer correct

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I currently have a Javascript Quiz that is working. I want to add the function of shuffle that will be able to shuffle the order that the answers are shown in for each question, and also be able to keep the answer correct if the position of the answer has changed.

For example if choice 2 is the correct answer but then the answers are shuffles I still want that correct answer to be linked to the correct choice box.

I look forward to your answers and thank you in advance.

```
const question = document.querySelector(`#question`);
const answerText = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.answer-text`));
const progressText = document.querySelector(`#progress-text`);
const scoreText = document.querySelector(`#score`);

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswer = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];


let questions = [
    {
        question: "Question 1",
        choice1: "A",
        choice2: "B",
        choice3: "C",
        choice4: "D",
        answer: 1,
    },
    {
        question: "Question 2",
        choice1: "A",
        choice2: "B",
        choice3: "C",
        choice4: "D",
        answer: 2,
    },
    {
        question: "Question 3",
        choice1: "A",
        choice2: "B",
        choice3: "C",
        choice4: "D",
        answer: 3,
    },
    {
        question: "Question 4",
        choice1: "A",
        choice2: "B",
        choice3: "C",
        choice4: "D",
        answer: 4,
    },
];

const scorePoints = 100;
const maxQuestions = 10;


let startQuiz = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions = [...questions];
    getNewQuestion();
};


let getNewQuestion = () => {
    if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter > maxQuestions) {
        localStorage.setItem("recentScore", score);

        return window.location.assign(`end-page.html`);
    }
    questionCounter++;
    progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter} of ${maxQuestions}`;


    const questionsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionsIndex];
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

    answerText.forEach((choice) => {
        const number = choice.dataset.number;
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
    });

    availableQuestions.splice(questionsIndex, 1);

    acceptingAnswer = true;
};



answerText.forEach((choice) => {
    choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (!acceptingAnswer) return;

        acceptingAnswer = false;
        const selectedChoice = e.target;
        const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset.number;

        let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

        if (classToApply === "correct") {
            incrementScore(scorePoints);
        }

        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

        setTimeout(() => {
            selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
            getNewQuestion();
        }, 1000);
    });
});



let incrementScore = (num) => {
    score += num;
    scoreText.innerText = score;
};

startQuiz();
```

I have tried using this shuffle algorithm but struggled to get it to work.

```js
for (let i = answerContainers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    answerContainers[i].parentNode.insertBefore(answerContainers[j], answerContainers[i]);
}
```